# Correcting rotation of imported Cesium GLTF/GLB file in Three.js

Tags: three.js, cesiumjs, gltf

I have a Cesium 3D tile set of buildings in Boston.  Here is a sample tile: [model.glb](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cf9g1zi2wv7fhyb/model.glb?dl=1).  When I import this tile into Three.js using THREE.GLTFLoader, the model is rotated relative to the XZ plane.  Through trial and error, I have found that I can straighten the model out by rotating it as follows:

```
model.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 4;
model.rotation.z = Math.PI / 10;
```

I suspect this rotation is due to Cesiuim using Earth-fixed frame axes (ITRF) by default.  How can I reverse this rotation automatically in Three.js (versus manually doing so via trial and error)?

Here is a screenshot of the model before I manually rotate it:

[image: model before manual rotation]

Here is a screenshot of the model after I manually rotate it:

[image: model after manual rotation]

Here is the geospatial information associated with the Cesium 3D tile:

```
{
  "boundingVolume":{"sphere":[1525116.05769,-4463608.36127,4278734.88048,28.30055]},
  "geometricError":0.09375,
  "content":{"url":"L12_0000110010123.b3dm"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
// Get the tile's cartesian center.
var cartesian = new Cesium.Cartesian3(1525116.05769, -4463608.36127, 4278734.88048);

// Get the tile's cartographic center.
var cartographic = Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(cartesian);

// Rotate the model.
model.rotation.x = -cartographic.latitude;
model.rotation.z = cartographic.longitude + Math.PI / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert "gltfUpAxis" to "Z" would work fine. Or you can try "Y" too.

```
"asset": {
    "gltfUpAxis": "Z",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
```